# send mails to multiple users without looping

Tags: php, email, smtp

I've written code to send mails to over 1200 users by looping 1200 times for generating unique random unsubscribe link to each user, but page is getting delayed due to this process. Please give me suggestions to accomplish this task. My code is below:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $unsubscribe_link = 'XXXXXX';
  mail(
    $result['user_email'],
    $subject,
    message($unsubscribe_link), html_headers($from_mail)
  );
}
```

Comment: Why would doing a single function for 1200 users be faster than repeating a function 1200 times?

Comment: This isn't how you should go about this. You need to run a queued task to do this.

Comment: This is not a appropriate process for a browser. You have to perform-it through commandline or background task. If really you don't have alternatives, you can try to perform-it through ajax, with progress bar and buttons to pause/resume/stop the process.

Comment: At moment i am doing with ajax only. Once user clicks on the button, I've configured to send mails to all users by ajax. is there any another way, rather than cron job?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to just concatenate email addresses in to the **to** field of PHP's mail function to avoid the loop:

```
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';
```

However as you are sending individual unsubscribe links to users by the looks of things this wouldn't be feasible (as recipients would see other's email addresses).  Plus, as mentioned in the comments already, this is probably a task better suited to being handled in the background.

The [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) docs suggest:

> It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.
>   For the sending of large amounts of email, see the » PEAR::Mail, and » PEAR::Mail_Queue packages.

I would have thought however that it might be safer (spam wise) and more effective to use a third party provider for your transactional emails such as [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/).